# How do replace a list with another list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am making a hangman game and I want to be able to replace the list of original words with a list of new words typed in by the user. At the minute my code is this:

```
gamewords[:] = newgamewords[:]
```

But this does not seem to work...

The original list is this:

```
gamewords= ['blue','violet','red','orange','fuchsia','cyan','magenta','azure','black','turquoise','pink','scarlet']
```

A word is then chosen for the list randomly

```
 word=gamewords[random.randint(0,len(gamewords)-1)]
```

i want to change it so that the word is chosen from the new list, how do i do this?

Comment: You will need to share more of the code in order to get any help.

Comment: This should replace all elements in `gamewords` with the elements from `newgamewords` - show us your current code and tell us why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question has been answered below. `gamewords = newgamewords` should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to do this:

```
gamewords = newgamewords[:]  # i.e. copy newgamewords
```

Another alternative would be

```
gamewords = list(newgamewords)
```

I find the latter more readable.

---

Note that when you 'copy' a list like both of these approaches do, changes to the new copied list will not effect the original. If you simply assigned `newgamewords` to `gamewords` (i.e. `gamewords = newgamewords`), then changes to `gamewords` *would* effect `newgamewords`.

---

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

Comment: Note that, depending on the use case, copying might not be needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want. There are two options:

1. `gamewords = newgamewords[:]`
2. `gamewords = newgamewords`

The difference is that the first option **copies** the elements of *newgamewords* and assigns it to *gamewords*. The second option just assigns a **reference** of *newgamewords* to *gamewords*. Using the second version, you would change the original *newgamewords*-list if you changed *gamewords*.

Because you didn't give more of your source code I can't decide which will work properly for you, you have to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice of functions to use to select one, or a set number of items randomly from a larger list would be `random.choice()` or `random.choices()`.

```
>>> gamewords= ['blue','violet','red','orange','fuchsia','cyan','magenta','azure','black','turquoise','pink','scarlet']
>>> random.choice(gamewords)
'turquoise'
>>> random.choice(gamewords)
'orange'
>>> random.choice(gamewords)
'cyan'
>>> random.choices(gamewords, k=3)
['fuchsia', 'orange', 'red']
>>> random.choices(gamewords, k=2)
['turquoise', 'black']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to find the answer to this but I had a similar issue and I resolved it using this method:

```rb
for x, y in zip(original_col, np.arange(0, len(original_col), 1)):
    df['Term Ldesc'] = df['Term Ldesc'].replace(x, y)
```

Hope this helps!